# ASP.NET Images are Getting 302 Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-7.5, http-status-code-302

I'm developing a new ASP.Net MVC 4.0 app locally.  It runs successfully in Casini.  Now I'd like to demo it to my client and expose it through IIS 7.5 running locally on my Win7 box. The problem is that all JPG images get a 302 redirect from IIS.  I've tried accessing images from /Images/*.jpg, /Content/*.jpg, and root /*.jpg.  What's interesting is that I can access other files types from any folder (like *.js files, *.css files, *.bmp files) just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: 302 is a redirect. What is it trying to redirect to? Have you looked at IIS? Is there a URL Rewrite in place?

Comment: it definitely sounds like they are getting caught by a rewriting filter either by iis or another rewriting tool. If not, check the it's MIME type entry in iis.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely due to Windows permissions on the root directory containing your web site.

When you set it up in IIS, you also need to grant access to the following users:

- IIS Anonymous user account: `IUSR`
- IIS Application Pool account: (`IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` is the default, replace the latter part if you've specified your own App Pool)

They only need the default read permissions, unless your web site creates files

[image: IIS website directory permissions screenshot]